# Snappy compression and decompression in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, compression, azure-databricks

I'm working on a problem where I have to compress a column data (datatype is string). While I can see that the data is getting compressed, decompressing it doesn't seem to display the original data which I compressed. I'm new to compression/decompression, so I'm having a hard time trying to work out the issue.

```
from snappy import * 
def compress_to_snappy(data):
  return snappy.compress(data,encoding="utf-8")
def decompress(data):
  return snappy.uncompress(data)
cSnappy = udf(compress_to_snappy, StringType())
dSnappy = udf(decompress, StringType())

comprsd_df = df.withColumn("compressed_col",cSnappy("metadata_col"))
```

Output: [the list has been converted to string prior the compression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aymEH.png)

```
decomprsd_df = comprsd_df.withColumn("decompressed_col",dSnappy("compressed_col"))
```

Output: [Decompression not happening?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpui8.png)

Comment: why do you really need this? data is compressed in Parquet/Delta by default, and uses Snappy under the hood. Using UDFs, especially Python UDFs, will make your execution much slower

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for your comment and apologies for replying so late. This particular test case was provided by my company to test out databricks.